# JavaFX menu item show shortcuts on right hand side

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Take for example the menu items from the edit menu in JavaFX Scene Builder

[image]

See how they display the shortcuts on the right? Is there any easy way to achieve the same effect using JavaFX? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can add an accelerator key in scene builder or add it directly in the fxml file like so

```
<?import javafx.scene.input.*?>
...
<MenuItem mnemonicParsing="true" onAction="#mnuSaveAction" text="%menu.title.save" fx:id="mnuSave">
   <accelerator>
      <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="S" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
   </accelerator>
</MenuItem>
```

`KeyCodeCombination` has two constructors, second example:

```
<MenuItem text="Renommer..."      onAction="#rename" mnemonicParsing="true">
   <accelerator>
      <KeyCodeCombination code="F2"><modifiers></modifiers></KeyCodeCombination>
   </accelerator>
</MenuItem>
```

If by "in javafx" you mean without using fxml you can use `mnuSave.setAccelerator(KeyCombination);`

Comment: Is specifying each attribute necessary? Like, if I want Ctrl+S, do you need to specify that alt="UP"?

Comment: Hmm, I got a runtime error (when the view loads) if I do not specify all the attributes. I would think that defaults would be OK, but I guess not.

Comment: @UnKnown Mine are aligned right.  If your's aren't, ask a question and add a screenshot and small sample or some details of your setup.

Comment: @brian http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545939/customize-javafx-menubar-to-remove-margin Here I asked. I want menu items same as Firefox have.

Answer (score 1):

If your are not using fxml file then you can add key combination like below.

```java
MenuItem gotoLine = new MenuItem("Goto");
KeyCombination gotoKeyCombination = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.G, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
gotoLine.setAccelerator(gotoKeyCombination);
gotoLine.setOnAction(event -> {
            System.out.println("CTRL+G event triggered");
            System.out.println(event.toString());
 });
```