# Customize JavaFX menuBar to remove margin

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

[image]

1: How I can remove this white space?

[image]

2: How I can add left line with space?

Here is my fxml's CSS code.

```
.menu-bar{
    -fx-use-system-menu-bar:true;
    -fx-border:none;
    -fx-background-color:#ececec;
    -fx-border-style:null;
    -fx-cursor:hand;
    -fx-padding:0px;
}
.menu-item{
    -fx-pref-width:200px;
    -fx-background-insets:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -fx-background-color:#ececec;
    -fx-padding:5px 0px 5px 30px;
}
.menu-item:hover{
    -fx-background-color:#4285f4;
}
```

In short I want to make menubar same as in Firefox as shown in 2nd Image.