# Javafx: How to Stretch Menu item Width

Tags: javafx

As you can see below how the menu items are stretched, I want to do the same.

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. The menu seems perfectly sized to fit two columns of justified text. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. An [mcve] will allow others to examine your approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209461/javafx-menu-item-show-shortcuts-on-right-hand-side).

Comment: Is `setMinSize()` what your asking for?

Comment: This menu image is taken from Google I want to do same as this through FXML

Answer (score 1):

The key to this is adding a `KeyCombination` to `menuItem.setAccelerator()`. The `Menu` should automatically stretch when you add `KeyCombinations` It will stretch based on your longest `MenuItem`.

**Programmatically:**

```
    MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("action");
    menuItem.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.T, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
    Menu menu = new Menu("File");
    menu.getItems().add(menuItem);
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    menuBar.getMenus().add(menu);
```

**FXML:**

```
<MenuItem mnemonicParsing="true" text="action">
    <accelerator>
        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="T" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
    </accelerator>
</MenuItem>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
<MenuBar>
   <Menu text="Menu Item">
      <items>
         <MenuItem text="New" style="-fx-padding: 0 70 0 70"/>
         <SeparatorMenuItem/>
         <MenuItem text="Exit" style="-fx-padding: 0 70 0 70"/>
      </items>
   </Menu>
</MenuBar>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is kind of old, but for the future visitors: you can do this by using css file like this:

```
.menu-item {
    -fx-padding: 5 5 80 5
}
```

You can play with the numbers to see what it changes.